# Android applications size > 50Mb. assets with jar libs?

Tags: java, android

my application reached the 50 Mb limit and I read about using assets at googles dev site and similar posts here but its still unclear for me what I can do if my app has more than 50Mb without having large resource files.
What I read about assets are that they meant to be used with audio files, pngs, textures, things like this. What can I do if my application is inflated by jar libs and/or much source code?

Thank you

Comment: http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

Comment: What are the jars for? Can they be downloaded later?

Comment: You could try shrinking your apk with proguard. This will cut unused code from your apk, and the jars you use as libraries. This makes the code as compact as possible while retaining functionality.

Comment: @Alberto. thx, I read this topic and thats part of my question if expansion files also can be used to host libraries?Is this a common approach?

Comment: @MeetTitan. Thanks for this , I will try it but it's still a question for me how could one solve this if source code is really so much that it still needs > 50Mb. thx for all answers

Comment: You might be able to get your apk to less than 50MB by shrinking it with proguard. Otherwise I would do as @Jared suggested and download them after the first app run if you can't get it below 50MB.